# Laravel 5.7, Eloquent: Property [X] does not exist on this collection instance, Many to Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I got this two tables (Estado(Status) and Proyecto(Proyect)), that have a pivot table in between called EstadoProyecto(statusProyect), I'm trying to access only the proyects that have either 2 or 3 in their id_status(id_estado) field, and that have the most recent date. It Works when using find(using either 2 or 3), but it gives me the error. " Eloquent: Property [proyectos] does not exist on this collection instance, Many to Many Relationship" when trying to send an array to the find method, or when using the get method. It gives me the same error when I'm not using the find method with only one value.
Here are my models, and the query I'm trying to use.
[model1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii19X.png) [model2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5Vrn.png)[model3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOkm5.png)

This is the query that works right now:
[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJuin.png)
Thanks in advance.
Diego :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you send multiple 'ids' to `find` it will return a Collection, `get` always returns a Collection ... Collection's are not models ... you would need a single `Estado` model instance to be able to access its `proyectos` relationship .. the other query works because it returns a single model instance or null, not a Collection, because you are only trying to get 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is returning a collection because there may be multiple entries for your model returned by the `find` method that Eloquent provides so you could either use the `first` method like this:

```
$estados = Estado::whereHas('proyectos', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('id_estado', [2, 3])
        ->orderBy('fecha_estado', 'DESC');
})
    ->with('proyectos', function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('id_estado', [2, 3])
            ->orderBy('fecha_estado', 'DESC');
    })
    ->first();
```

With the above snippet, to get multiple results that match those conditions you would only need to replace the `first` method with `get`

The above code with give you can an instance of a single `Estado` model.

Otherwise, if you are going to use something along the original approach you can use `get` and return a collection, you can iterate over them in a foreach loop:

```
$estados = Estado::whereHas('proyectos', function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('fecha_estado', 'DESC');
})
    ->with('proyectos')
    ->get();

foreach ($estados as $estado) {
    $estado->proyectos->id;
}
```

Or you could access the items in the collection like you would an array, granted you know that you definitely have the entry required in your results:

```
$estados[0]->proyectos->id;
```

If you are looking to get just one result, using Eloquent's `first` method is often the best option for this.

I hope this helps!

Extra info:

The `find` method in Eloquent can accept either a single value or an array of values as an argument and in the case of either no value being passed to it or an array of values being passed to it, a Collection may be returned rather than an instance of a single model.

The `get` method on the other hand can be used without supplying any arguments and will return collection every time (although these can still hold no items if the underlying query did not yield any results)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, the first method works wonderfully. Unfortunately, the second method returns an error sayind that find needs at least 1 parameter, idk if it could be the version of Laravel thah im using. error: "Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::find(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIGECOP\app\Http\Controllers\ReportesController.php on line 56 and at least 1 expected"

Comment: No problem, I have updated my answer. It is correct that the `find` method requires an argument. The`get` method is the substitute method that returns a collection and can be used without supplying any arguments.

Comment: The first method has one problem, i think i need the first() method before the where() method, because its giving me the results of the older registry.

Comment: For example, i got proyect #1 with status = 1 date 12/10/19, then i got proyect #1 with status = 2 date 13/10/19, after that i got proyecto #1 with status = 1 14/10/19. The output should be 0 proyects, but it returns with the 2 registry with status = 2.

Comment: You only need to add the `where` method if you actually have a column you want to filter by. I'll update my answer with another example.